# Is *reading* canvas ImageData 32-bit typed arrays much faster than 8-bit?

Tags: canvas, getimagedata, typed-arrays

I know that manipulating 32-bit typed ImageData arrays is significantly faster (2x) than 8-bit. Is the same true for simply reading them?

When writing, you reduce the work from 3 index increments and 4 assignments to 3 bit-shifts and and a single assignment, plus reducing loop overhead by 75%. To read them back you'd similarly reduce loop overhead and convert the increments to bit-shifts but would still need to assign 4 separate vars, for r,g,b,a.

here's the bench for manip diffs: http://jsperf.com/canvas-pixel-manipulation/24

if the majority of the speed increase comes from reducing assignment, then it may not be worth converting my read-heavy code to typed arrays. anyone have experience with this before i spend time writing another bench?

thanks!